# Using WebStorm with Parse.com

Tags: webserver, parse-platform, webstorm

I'm completely new to web development including WebStorm, but I do know game development, and through that I've used Parse.com a number of times with iOS games. I know Parse has a JS SDK, but how would I use that with WebStorm? The whole web server is a bit unclear to me, does the web server with WebStorm automatically kick in for anything you publish? Or can you turn it off? Do I have to turn it off to work online with the Parse SDK?

Answer (score 5):

If you're on a mac, below steps should work:

1. **WebStorm** → **Preferences** → **JavaScript** → **Libraries** → **Add**
2. Press on the **+** button and add the Parse JavaScript SDK.

   [image]
3. You should now see the Parse SDK listed in the libraries.

   [image]

Now to run the application locally:

1. Run `npm install parse` to install Node's Parse module.
2. Include `var Parse = require('parse').Parse;` in your `main.js`
3. **Run** → **Edit Configurations** and make sure that Node interpreter is set to `/usr/local/bin/node`.
4. Now use **Run** → **Run 'main.js'** to run your application.

Answer (score 3):

you need to download the javascript SDK (parse-1.2.17.js) and configure it as a javascript library in WebStorm (Settings/javaScript/Libraries, Add...)

You don't have to use the built-in server if you don't need it. Just configure your own web server is settings/deployment, like it's shown in http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Remote_JavaScript_debugging_with_WebStorm_and_PHPStorm#Configuring_access_to_the_Web_server