# Guide to setting up/using the Parse JS SDK with Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, webstorm

I'm just starting to get into JS development. I'm using WebStorm. Is there a guide anywhere as to how to setup Webstorm to work with Parse? What I don't understand is how the whole webserver aspect works with Parse. The built in webserver is obviously local, but how can you run/test/debug parse JS code in Webstorm which is accessing the online parse server, via webstorm?

Answer (score 2):

Please see http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5510993#5510993 for some information

Answer (score 0):

Now to run the application locally on a Mac:

1. Run `npm install parse` to install Node's Parse module.
2. Include `var Parse = require('parse').Parse;` in your `main.js`
3. **Run** → **Edit Configurations** and make sure that Node interpreter is set to `/usr/local/bin/node`.
4. Now use **Run** → **Run 'main.js'** to run your application.

To add autocompletion, follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899791/577878) - another helpful tutorial is [The JavaScript SDK in Node.js](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-javascript-sdk-in-node-js/). Quick example code:

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;

Parse.initialize("Your App Id", "Your JavaScript Key");

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.find({
  success: function(users) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
      console.log(users[i].get('username'));
    }
  }
});
```